# Build a single list of element from bi-dimensional array list

Tags: python, arrays

I have the following list of lists:

```
[[url1, data1],[url2, data2],[url3, data3]]
```

I want to build a simple list of the URLs.

I'm doing this:

```
  if results:
    for row in results.get('rows'):
      data.append(row[:1])
    print data
```

for this result (a list of lists):

```
[[url1],[url2],[url3]]
```

I would like to have a simple list, like this :

```
[url1,url2,url3]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want the `url`, and your data is basically a list of lists then you can just use the `index` number, in this case `[0]` as url is the 1st element in a nested list

```
l = [['url1', 'data1'],['url2', 'data2'],['url3', 'data3']]
endlist = []
for i in l:
    endlist.append(i[0])

print endlist
```

Output:

```
['url1', 'url2', 'url3']
```

However, make sure how your data is structured. A list of lists looks like `[[],[],[]]`, where each nested list is seperated by a `,` (comma) which is absent in the example you posted.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood you correctly, you need this:

```
results = [[url_1, data_1], [url_2, data_2], ...]
urls = list()
for r in results:
    # r = [url_i, data_i]
    urls.append(r[0])
```